# What is the difference of "such as its" and "such was its"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I only heard of "such as its", but not "such was its".

What is the meaning of such was its below?

> A horse like this had never been seen before — **such was its**
>   splendor, its majesty, its strength

Comment: Past tense of 'such is its'

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, what is the different of such as its and such is its? I have never heard of such is its..

Comment: meaning 3 - http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/such?q=such

Comment: It's an _inversion_.  "Its splendor, its majesty, its strength _was such_ [as had never been seen before].       (however,  I would have used "were" because three qualities are mentioned.)

Answer (score 2):

It's an *inversion*.  Rearranged, it reads like this:

- "Its splendor, its majesty, its strength *was such* [as had never been seen before].

  (however,  I would have used "were", because three qualities are mentioned.)